# On Hold Audio/Data Compression

Tags: distortion, compression-algorithm

Anybody know what kind of algorithms/applications they use for this?  Cuz I'm on hold right now and whenever the music overloads the system there's this wicked pink noise distortion that takes over the entire signal.  I want to use it on everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In India, when I was recording localization IVRs, they used A-law 8-bit/8-kHz. I am not sure whether it is the international standard for telecom services. I am sure Europe is A-law algorithm as well and Northern America has u-law (Mu-Law) algorithm.

Comment: I encountered the same specs when looking into audio for phone systems here in NZ, so it sounds like they are pretty standard worldwide.

Comment: @g.a.harry Cheers!